# Convention based approach for configuring services based on Operating System in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I recently created an ASP.NET service using 1.0.0-rc1-update1 on coreclr (x64). So, the service is capable of running on all supported Operating Systems; very cool! My service just exposes a simple "TODO" API and uses the Entity Framework 7.0 ORM. For persistence, it employs a Sqlite DB on Linux and SQL Server DB on Windows.

I am wondering if there is a convention based approach to allow Startup.cs to handle differing service configurations for the various Operating Systems? For example, my EF configuration differs because it uses Sqlite on Linux and SQL Server on Windows.

The following article does detail some convention based approaches to configuration, but it seems to only allow for different methods for the higher level abstractions of "Development", "Staging", "Production" environments:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

Currently, I am just injecting the IRuntimeEnviroment in the constructor of Startup.cs and saving it. Then, when ConfigureServices is invoked, I check the OperatingSystem property of the IRuntimeEnvironment and adjust the EF configuration accordingly (my full Startup.cs provided below)...

Any guidance on other (or recommended) approaches would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public IRuntimeEnvironment RuntimeEnv { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IRuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        RuntimeEnv = runtimeEnv;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (RuntimeEnv.OperatingSystem == "Windows")
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
        else if (RuntimeEnv.OperatingSystem == "Linux")
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:SqlLiteConnection"];

            var path = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlite()
                .AddDbContext<TodoContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Filename=" + Path.Combine(path, "TodoApp.db")));
        }

        services
            .AddMvcCore(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.Clear();
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new HttpNotAcceptableOutputFormatter());
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new HttpNoContentOutputFormatter());
            })
            .AddJsonFormatters();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseMvc();

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Verbose);

        loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
    }
}
```